# What's the status of Meta 2 support in the Perl toolchain?

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm about to release new versions of some of [my modules](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/), and I'm wondering which metadata files I should include in the distributions.  The [CPAN Meta Spec version 2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aSpec) has been released, but I'm not sure how well supported it is right now in the Perl toolchain.

I'm thinking of including both a v2 META.json and a [v1.4](http://module-build.sourceforge.net/META-spec-v1.4.html) META.yml.  Tools that support Meta 2 should ignore META.yml when both are present.  Tools that predate Meta 2 ought to be looking for META.yml.

The problem would be tools that prefer META.json to META.yml, but expect META.json to be in v1.x format.  Are there any tools like that?  How common are they?  Is this a good idea, or will it cause problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

META.yml v1.4 can be read by various tools, META.json v2, AFAIK, is used only by search.cpan.org. Any distribution that used Dist::Zilla has both, with META.json v2, so you can use v2 without causing any more problems and I don't know any tool that expects META.json v1.4.

(after looking for something) I found out that there is one tool that uses META.json v1.4 and it's mine :). It's a program to add CPAN modules to Freshmeat, but I'll just rewrite it.